# What (if anything) Does Superfino Indicate on a Package of Italian Arborio Rice?

Tags: rice, italian-cuisine

Local stores want my first born child for Arborio. I have found much better deals on Amazon. Most packages say "superfino". Does that actually *mean* anything?

Comment: Spanish paella or any decent quality short grained rice should work fine for risotto, you pay a premium for top quality italian risotto rice in the states. Long grain rice can be used, adding a dollop of creme fraiche at the end will top up the creaminess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Italian rice is graded according to length, shape, size and the amount of broken or whole grains.
Commune or originario is the least expensive and most basic.
Semifino is medium length, maintains firmness, not typically used in risotto.
Fino is relatively long, large and has tapered grains...Stays firm when cooked.  Can be used in risotto...a "fine" rice.
Superfino is the top grade...the most fat and largest grains.  They take the longest to cook because they absorb a large amount of moisture, but still remain firm.  Look for rice from Arborio or Carnaroli.  This is what the best risotto is made from.

[Citation](http://articles.latimes.com/1997/oct/15/food/fo-43048)